# Manipulate values in pandas DataFrame columns based on matching IDs from another DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes like the following examples:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['20', '50', '100'], 'b': [1, np.nan, 1],
                 'c': [np.nan, 1, 1]})
df_id = pd.DataFrame({'b': ['50', '4954', '93920', '20'],
                      'c': ['123', '100', '6', np.nan]})

print(df)
     a    b    c
0   20  1.0  NaN
1   50  NaN  1.0
2  100  1.0  1.0

print(df_id)
       b    c
0     50  123
1   4954  100
2  93920    6
3     20  NaN
```

For each identifier in `df['a']`, I want to null the value in `df['b']` if there is no matching identifier in any row in `df_id['b']`. I want to do the same for column `df['c']`.

My desired result is as follows:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['20', '50', '100'], 'b': [1, np.nan, np.nan],
                 'c': [np.nan, np.nan, 1]})
print(result)
     a    b    c
0   20  1.0  NaN
1   50  NaN  NaN    # df_id['c'] did not contain '50'
2  100  NaN  1.0    # df_id['b'] did not contain '100'
```

My attempt to do this is here:

```
for i, letter in enumerate(['b','c']):
    df[letter] = (df.apply(lambda x: x[letter] if x['a']
                   .isin(df_id[letter].tolist()) else np.nan, axis = 1))
```

The error I get:

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'isin'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

This is in Python 3.5.2, Pandas version 20.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem using this instead:

```
for letter in ['b','c']: # took off enumerate cuz i didn't need it here, maybe you do for the rest of your code
    df[letter] = df.apply(lambda row: row[letter] if row['a'] in (df_id[letter].tolist()) else np.nan,axis=1)
```

just replace `isin` with `in`.

The problem is that when you use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on `df`, x will represent `df rows`, so when you select `x['a']` you're actually selecting one element.

However, [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) is applicable for series or list-like structures which raises the error so instead we just use `in` to check if that element is in the list.

Hope that was helpful. If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: I just read the docs again and realized that isin() returns a boolean series. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Adapting a hard-to-find answer from [Pandas New Column Calculation Based on Existing Columns Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147435/pandas-new-column-calculation-based-on-existing-columns-values):

```
for i, letter in enumerate(['b','c']):
    mask = df['a'].isin(df_id[letter])
    name = letter + '_new'
    # for some reason, df[letter] = df.loc[mask, letter] does not work
    df.loc[mask, name] = df.loc[mask, letter]
    df[letter] = df[name]
    del df[name]
```

This isn't pretty, but seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bigger Dataframe and performance is important to you, you can first build a mask df and then apply it to your dataframe.
First create the mask:

```
mask = df_id.apply(lambda x: df['a'].isin(x))
       b      c
0   True  False
1   True  False
2  False   True
```

This can be applied to the original dataframe:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].mask(~mask, np.nan)
     a    b    c
0   20  1.0  NaN
1   50  NaN  NaN
2  100  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: I originally tried using a mask, but ran into the same errors described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913201/pandas-replace-values-in-a-dataframe-based-on-a-boollean-dataframe). Also, this doesn't seem to replicate the desired result.

Comment: Yes, your right, i messed up the logic because the boolean mask indicates where the replace should happen. I fixed it in the post by inverting the mask. What excatly was your problem with the mask? I think the solution in the question you linked was quite elegant.

Comment: The poster of that question and I both got 'ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64' when attempting to use a mask that way. It seems like there's some version-specific bug with either Python or Pandas or some mix of the two.